# Start AnimationDrawable at specific frame?

Tags: android, animation, animationdrawable

I got an AnimationDrawable like so:

```
 AnimationDrawable ani = new AnimationDrawable();       
        ani.addFrame(first, duration);
        ani.addFrame(second, duration);
        ani.addFrame(third, duration);
        ani.setOneShot(true);
```

And started like so:

```
ani.start();
```

I was wondering if it is possible to start directly, at lets say the second frame. Are there any ways of doing this? I need it for a game where I want to be able to resume the exact frame as when I hit my pause button calling:

```
ani.stop();
```

For now it starts the entire animation again after resumeing from "pause mode".

Comment: Hi, did you get answer/solution for your question? I am also interested in! Thx

Answer (score 0):

When animtaion stop,use this method : ani.selectDrawable(index);