# AnimationDrawable start at specific frame?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have the same question as this [question asked 2 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867437/start-animationdrawable-at-specific-frame?answertab=oldest#tab-top) with no valid answer *(please do not close this question for duplicated content; there is no answer/solution yet)*.

So, I have a `AnimationDrawable` made programmatically and I would like to start the animation at a specific frame.

When I stop and I start the animation again by specifying a frame the animation displays the right frame but just after jumps back to the 1st frame to run the animation. For example:

```
// Stopping the animation 
animation.stop();

// Starting the animation again
animation.start();
animation.selectDrawable(9);
```

What should be the right practice?

Do I have to recreate the animation on the fly and set the frame 9 as 1st frame in the animation such as `animation.addFrame(myDrawable9, duration)` and the next frames would be 10, 11, 12...1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8?

Any fast an easy way to do that?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

So, unfortunately there's no public `setFrame()` method. However, it implements `Runnable`, and the implementation of `run()` calls `nextFrame(false)` which calls through to `setFrame()`. So, it's certainly a hack, but you could implement a method such as:

```
public static void setAnimationFrame(AnimationDrawable anim, int frame) {
    for (int i = 0; i < frame; i++) {
        anim.run();
    }
}
```

Which should advance the Drawable to the proper frame.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am trying to fit your hack in my code. I let you know.